# Schengen Visa for Job Interview, Minimum balance in Account

Tags: schengen, belgium, proof-provenance-of-funds, proof-of-employment

I have been invited for a job interview in Belgium. The employer is sponsoring the cost of travel and stay. I have a few questions.

1. I am planning to apply for Business visa. Is this the right visa category? Or should I apply for visitor visa. I am aware that, there is no seperate category as such. I just have to tick appropriate checkbox in the visa form.
2. I work in India. I have payslips and Income Tax returns. I don't keep much money in my account. I pay home loan & car loan EMIs, and invest some money in Mutual funds. I get my salary on 1st every month. But due to aforementioned reasons by 10th I have about 10000Rs left in my account each month. How much is the minimum balance required in my account if potential employer is sponsoring my travel? And for what duration? Can I use money I put for savings in my wife's account? She is the sole owner of that account. If so then what documents do I need of my wife?

I am aware that I need about 30-50 Euro/day. But if you are being sponsored then also do I need to show that I have money to support my visit?

Comment: It all looks pretty clear and straight-forward, but what does your wife have to do with it? Is she travelling with you?

Comment: @GayotFow: She is not travelling with me but if required, I can show savings in her bank account. I do not keep enough liquid money in my account.

Comment: It may be useful to note that often, "sponsoring your trip" in theory means "reimbursing you for your trip" in practice, meaning you may be expected to pay all costs upfront and be repaid later. 10000Rs is under €135, which in Europe is visiting expenses for only two or three days. Flights get delayed, hotels cancel, and cars arrive late, leaving you to cover these additional expenses out of pocket before getting reimbursed later. I would be quite uncomfortable traveling with so little money relative to living expenses in my host country, which are significant in Belgium. Bear this in mind

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no minimum balance requirement. What is required is:

1. Proof of legal income.
2. Proof of ties to home (such as property, steady job, income, investments, family) so that you are compelled to return.
3. Ability to financially support your trip.

Now, for #3, the majority of your costs are being paid by your (potential) employer. They should prepare a letter (on their letterhead, and signed by an authorized person) addressed to the embassy which states the following:

1. Your complete name (as in your passport)
2. The dates of your travel.
3. The purpose of your trip.
4. The costs being covered (accommodation, travel ticket, daily expenses)

A sample letter template could be:

> To Visa Officer, Belgian Consulate General in India:
>
> I/We have invited Mr. Nambaliya to Belgium
>   for the purposes of interviewing him for the position of ___________
>   from __ / __ / 2017 till __ / __ / 2017.
>
> For the purposes of the above mentioned trip, I/We  will pay
>   and assuming the following costs:
>
> 1. Return air ticket to/from _________ .
> 2. Hotel accommodation from __ / __ / 2017 till __ / ___ / 2017.
> 3. Per Diem in the amount of ________ .
>
> Sincerely Yours,
>
> Mr. CEO or HR Manager
>   The Company

That letter, along with the normal documents:

1. Your salary certificate
2. Your bank statement(s)
3. Pay slips + tax documents
4. Ticket + Hotel (provided by your hosts)

Comment: Excellent answer. Very well described. Makes it all clear. Thanks.

Comment: very nice, +1, and a minor edit

Answer (score 5):

- You need money for your cost of living during the trip, and it must be clear where it comes from. In this case, it comes from your company. Show those documents.
- You need a stable financial situation where you come from. That's not just a question of having a minimum balance in the bank, it is a question of earning more than you spend, in a legal, predictable, and well documented pattern.

Comment: If my potential employer is sponsoring my whole trip then also do I need to have enough money to cover my trip cost? What is the meaning of sponsoring then?

Comment: @nambaliya, for a short-term visa you should have a stable situation at home, with enough income for your living when you return. That's why a minimum balance is *not enough*.

Comment: I do have a pretty stable job here and regular income also. I think that should be enough to justify my case. Thank for the help o.m.